# How to configure CORS in Parse Server?

Tags: parse-platform

This one below is the Parse Server.

https://parseplatform.org/

Please how could I create CORS settings in Parse Server?

Comment: It depends on how you are deploying Parse Server. You can do it in a reverse proxy that you may have running on top of Parse Server. Or you can set it up on your Express.js app in which your Parse Server is mounted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://parseplatform.org/parse-server/api/5.2.0/ParseServerOptions.html

you can see that there are two environment variables that lets you
add values to headers Access-Control-Allow-Headers and Access-Control-Allow-Origin of the response. The two env variables are 'allowHeaders' and 'allowOrigin'. I have set them in the 'config.json' that is used to create the parse server.